# Can I set dual external monitors on Thinkpad X220?

Tags: 11.10, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 on ThinkPad X220.

Browsing through the ThinkWiki pages I stumbled upon [this information](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Installing_Ubuntu_11.04_(Natty_Narwhal)_on_a_ThinkPad_X220#Multiple_monitors):

> **Multiple monitors**
>
> Configuring an extended desktop over two monitors led to malfunction.
> Side-by-side worked, one above the other did not.
>
> In natty the solution was just to avoid the layouts that caused the
> malfunction.
>
> The problems appear to have been completely solved in Ubuntu 11.10
> (Oneiric Ocelot).

Has anyone of you managed to make X220 work with a dual monitor setup? Does it require UltraBase? Any special tweaks or modifications?

Comment: Apparently [works good](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2012/04/ubuntu-review.html#comment-510071494) in 12.04.

Comment: More info about UltraBase [here](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Dual-screens-on-x220-amp-Ubuntu-12-04/td-p/769331) & [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo-ibm/670074-dual-screens-x220-ubuntu-12-04-a.html).

Comment: The [link](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Dual-screens-on-x220-amp-Ubuntu-12-04/td-p/769331) radek provided says that one would have to turn off the laptop's LCD (LVDS) to run two external monitors at the same time since the Sandy Bridge processor of the X220 is limited to outputting to two monitors at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is different. With 11.04 it was a bit unstable. With 12.04, it works like a charm. (I never bothered with 11.10).

Try it.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Do you use ultrabase? Is it possible to connect two screens using ports of your laptop only?

Comment: Yes, I use ultrabase. I will check the two external monitors on Sunday. I know it can do two external monitors with Windoze, so I do not expect a problem here.

Comment: Thanks for that! Do you use one DisplyPort and one VGA cable? Or are there other options with ultrabase?

Comment: VGA+DisplayPort. I just need to find a display port cable.

Comment: I finally managed to connect two monitors, one with DisplayPort and another with VGA. It seems to work. I could not have both monitors work together with the tablet. But, the display went just fine. The machine suspended and recovered from suspended mode nicely, resuming the same configuration. Ubuntu 12.04 was also able to detect undocking and change the monitors configuration correctly. For some reason, I could find a hibernate menu option, so I could not test this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for update. Is ultrabase necessary for such setup? Would it be possible to use vga and display ports from laptop itself?

Answer (score 1):

It works but it is unstable. For example, if you hibernate with the dual displays active and resume with just the laptop's screen, it may be that you will get no display (actually, the display will be full of useless vertical black and white lines). The only way to get out of this is to power cycle or remote ssh and reboot.

On other occasions, if the external screen was the main screen, you may end up having the laptop screen being ok but the Unity focus still be on the external screen (which you unplugged), thereby preventing you from doing anything useful with the desktop. You cannot even reboot since you cannot clock on anything. Again, the solution is to reboot or ssh remotely.

I am using both setups, one with [Ultrabase](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd010992-thinkpad-ultrabase-series-3-overview) at the office and one without at home.

Comment: Thanks for information. I think I could live without hibernation. Just one question - for the setup without ultrabase - how do you connect? One DisplayPort cable & one VGA? Or some adapter?

Comment: Oups... I guess I read your original post too quickly, I did not realised tha tyour said 2 EXTERNAL monitors. I am using 1 external and the laptop screen. Sorry for the confusion. But even with my simpler setup it is not yet stable. Back your your original question; I did not try... sorry.